# Decoding JSON string to terraform map

Tags: terraform

I'm using the [HTTP data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/http/data_source.html) to retrieve data from an internal service. The service returns JSON data.

I can't interpolate the returned JSON data and look up data in it.

For example:

module A

```
data "http" "json_data" {
    url = "http://myservice/jsondata"

    # Optional request headers
    request_headers {
       "Accept" = "application/json"
    }
}

output "json_data_key" {
    value = "${lookup(data.http.json_data.body, "mykey")}"
}
```

main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
   region = "${var.region}"
   version = "~> 0.1"
}

module "moduleA" {
   source = "../../../terraform-modules/moduleA"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
    ami = "ami-2757f631"
    instance_type = "${module.moduleA.json_data_key}"
}
```

The lookup function will fail to extract the key within the JSON data.

Is there any way to decode the JSON data into a terraform map ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so it seems to be that the way to do the is by using the external data, as it return a *map* from a json response.
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html

terraform version v0.10.6

Comment: The URL linked here returns a 404 for anyone else looking for an answer in the future

Answer (score 22):

```
variable "json" {
  default = "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"
}

data "external" "json" {
  program = ["echo", "${var.json}"]
}

output "map" {
  value = "${data.external.json.result}"
}
```

Comment: how, where is `var.json` defined in this example? is it read from an external file?

Comment: It is just a variable with the JSON string.

Comment: Added explicit variable declaration

Answer (score 7):

Since 0.12 version of the Terraform you can use `jsondecode` function to decode json into a Terraform map. More details on: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsondecode.html

example from the page above:

```
> jsondecode("{\"hello\": \"world\"}")
{
  "hello" = "world"
}
> jsondecode("true")
true
```

Comment: The Jsondecode function does not necessarily return a map. In fact, I personally haven't ever seen it return a map. From my experience, it always returns an object. I'm sure this is heavily dependent on the structure of your JSON string.

Answer (score 7):

Not directly related to map convertion, but here's an additional sample with `jsondecode` if you got a multi-value secret (=JSON) in AWS SecretsManager & you want to use separate values from it in another service as I've struggled with this.

Retrieving the secret:

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "oauth_client" {
  name = "oauth-client"
}

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "oauth_client" {
  secret_id = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.oauth_client.id
}
```

Using it at Lambda, as an example:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  [...]
  environment {
    variables = {
      OAUTH_CLIENT_ID     = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.oauth_client.secret_string)["client_id"]
      OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.oauth_client.secret_string)["client_secret"]
    }
  }
}
```