# Convert string or array to map in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform v0.10.7
    AWS provider version = "~> 1.54.0"

Are there any examples how to translate a string or list into a map in Terraform?

We are setting up Consul key/value store like this:

```
consul kv put common/rules/alb/service1 name=service1,port=80,hcproto=http,hcport=80
```

I can access keys and values properly, and now I am trying to use values as a map in Terraform:

```
data "consul_key_prefix" "common" {
  path_prefix = "common/rules"
}

output "common"{
value = "${jsonencode(lookup(var.CommonRules,element(keys(var.CommonRules),1))) }"
}
```

*$ terraform output*

```
common = "{name=service1,port=80,hcproto=http,hcport=80}"
```

But when I try to access it as a map, it doesn't work:

```
output "common"{
value = "${lookup(jsonencode(lookup(var.CommonRules,element(keys(var.CommonRules),1))),"name") }"
}
```

*$ terraform output*

(no response)

I tried few things here - e.g. splitting these values and joining them again into a list, and then running "map" function but it doesn't work either:

*$ terraform output*

```
common = [
    name,
    service1,
    port,
    80,
    hcproto,
    http,
    hcport,
    80
]
```

and then trying to create map of that list:

```
output "common2" {
value = "${map(split(",",join(",",split("=",lookup(var.CommonRules,element(keys(var.CommonRules),1))))))}"
}
```

but it doesn't work either.

So my question would be - does anyone has working example where he did translated string (or list) into a map?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the `external` data source as defined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46371424/decoding-json-string-to-terraform-map). It looks like if you `echo` out the output from the `consul_key_prefix` data source in the `external` data source, the output of that will be a map based on its json output.

Comment: Yes, it would work with External data source, thanks, however for this one I wanted to see if there is any way to use only Terraform, but looks like there is not in Terraform < v0.12

Answer (score 2):

`jsondecode` function in upcoming Terraform `v0.12` would be the tool to solve this problem.

[`jsondecode` function github issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10363)