# Interpreting aws secrets in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, hcl

I have the following code..

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "db_password" {
name = "${var.db_secret}" 
}

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "db_password" { 
secret_id = "${data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.db_password.id}" 
}


master_password = "${data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.db_password.secret_string}"
```

which returns the secret_string in this case of

```
 secret_string = {"Test":"TestPassword"}
```

how do i cut out and use the TestPassword section of the secret for use as my master_password?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46371424/decoding-json-string-to-terraform-map

Answer (score 3):

I had to fake up your Secrets endpoint but this test endpoint returns the same json:

So in tf...

```
data "external" "secret_string" {
  program = ["curl", "http://echo.jsontest.com/Test/Testpassword"]
}

output "json_data_key" {
  value = "${data.external.secret_string.result}"
}

output "PASSWORD" {
  value = "${lookup(data.external.secret_string.result, "Test")}"
}
```

that last output is what you were after?

```
${lookup(data.external.secret_string.result, "Test")}
```

Which gives you:

```
data.external.secret_string: Refreshing state...

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

PASSWORD = Testpassword
json_data_key = {
  Test = Testpassword
}
```

So it is certainly possible to parse json before 0.12......

Comment: Thanks, i had worked something out in console doing something similar, but wasn't sure how to chain them together like you have.
seems a bit messy for secretsmanager to be usable in TF.. but i want to be able to leverage this product for more than my applications...

Comment: Cant say i've know your problem so i don't know what the solution is.  if your after wanting to get secrets into config files then i would try confd, consul_template or gomplate for that.

Answer (score 2):

Considering this is JSON, you probably need to wait for `jsondecode` in Terraform `v0.12` to solve the problem.

[jsondecode function Github issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10363)